# How to get DataValidation in Apache POI 3.9?

Tags: apache-poi

I am using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to write and read excel files,my poi version is **3.9**,but now I faced a problem and do not find a good solution to solve it.

First I am use poi to write some datas to the excel table and will use **[DataValidation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidation.html)** to add some prompt information in the table header,as the picture shown below:

The value in the cell is **ABSInterention**,and the prompt title is **wrxuoh**.After the excel generated successfully,other users will add some modification to the data cell and I need to read and parse the excel file and I want to get the prompt value **wrxuoh** again.So my question is:

**When I read excel file using POI3.9,how can I get all the DataValidations for the current sheet?**

I am using **HSSFWorkbook** and **HSSFSheet**.I found there is a method called **getDataValidations** in the **[POI Sheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html)**,but I can not find this method in my poi3.9 jar file and also can not find it in the POI3.9 javadoc.

any help would be grateful!

[image]

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest version of Apache POI? It would seem that the method you want was added more recently

Comment: I just checked the Apache POI3.10.1 and still can not find this method in the javadoc,which version do you refer to?

Comment: @Gagravarr I checked that POI3.11 and found it was there!But the POI3.11 is not a stable version,besides this method,is there any other way that can meet my demand,please?

Comment: You could backport the feature to 3.9 if you really really wanted to... But you're probably much better off upgrading to 3.11 beta 3 to get it, then upgrade again to 3.11 final in a few weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - you can't

That functionality was added to Apache POI after the 3.9 release you mention in your question

As per the [Apache POI Changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), you need to upgrade to at least POI 3.11 beta 3 to use that feature. 3.11 final, when it comes out shortly, will be the first stable release to include it

Comment: ,it seems that you are one of poi development team member,could you tell me when the stable release will be available for the version poi.3.11 beta?

Comment: Few weeks, but no final decision as it depends on if anyone reports any major bugs in 3.11 beta 3!

Comment: Could you tell me your skype account,please? I think you are a POI developer,but I found some problems when I tried to recompile the source code myself.